# Cerrando aplicacion en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación (Forms) de VB.NET necesito que cuando pulse el botón de cerrar escriba en un fichero un texto, por lo tanto capturo el evento de cierre de Form para luego escribir en el fichero de la siguiente forma:

```
Private Sub FrmMainPlatform_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("fichero.txt", False)
    file.Write("texto")
    file.Close()
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Pero el cerrar la aplicación me doy cuenta de que no la termina, es decir el Visual Studio sigue corriendo y si la ejecuto manualmente en el visor de tareas sigo viendo la aplicación y no quiero abrir tantas instancias como veces la ejecute

Comment: que pasa si quitas el Application.Exit()?

Comment: Lo mismo, sigue corriendo la aplicación, no se cierra

Comment: No tendras otro formulario abierto entonces? uh otra cosa que todavia esta procesando? si cerras el unico formulario que hay, la aplicacion deberia cerrarse sin que hagas el exit. Si sacas el codigo para grabar el archivo se cierra?

Comment: Si tengo otro formulario abierto, pero he añadido el codigo close de ese formulario, si quito el codigo tampoco se cierra, y si añado Me.close() me da stackoverflow

Comment: El problema esta en que un formulario se ve que trata de mantener al otro abierto o algo asi.. si haces me.close, vuelve a querer ejecutar este evento que vuelve a querer hacer me.close eternamente... Tendriamos que tener un [mcve] para poder ver que es lo que queda abierto

Comment: Y existe alguna forma de cerrar por completo la aplicacion?

Comment: Application.Exit deberia cerrarla, pero hay algo en otro lado que queda vivo y no la cierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero pienso que deberías echar un vistazo a [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046019/winforms-application-exit-vs-enviroment-exit-vs-form-close#answer-13046082)

Por mi parte yo uso `End` cuando no quiero que se quede ningún subproceso abierto:

El siguiente ejemplo usa la sentencia `End` para terminar con la ejecución de un programa con el consentimiento del usuario, como se plantea [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement):

```
Sub Form_Load()      
  If MsgBox("Deseas terminar la aplicación?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
      End
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo Pienso que debe de ser por esto, y puedes solucionar-lo así

```html
' Has de Añadir un Reloj ( Control Timer ) y Hacer Que Allí Se Produzca el evento de Cierre del Formulario
    ' No se Puede Provocar la salida Dentro de esa Sub, Esa Sub solo sirve para Revocar la orden de cierre del mismo... 

Dim SeHizo as Boolean = False
    Private Sub FrmMainPlatform_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing   
 Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        If SeHizo = False Then 
          SeHizo = True
          e.Cancel = True
          Timer1.Interval = 1000
          Timer1.Enabled = True 
        End If
        'Application.Exit()
    End Sub

     Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Enabled = False
file =  My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("fichero.txt", False)
        file.Write("texto")
        file.Close()
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
```